# Flutter:- How to check Gif is loaded or not

Tags: image, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, gif

I did the display gif in image widget and I want to check the gif is loaded or not.

```
 Image.asset(
    "assets/mmgif/splash_final.gif",gaplessPlayback: true,
    frameBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, int frame,
        bool wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
       
      if (wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
        MyPrint(tag: "CheckLoaded", value: wasSynchronouslyLoaded.toString());
        return child;
      }
      return AnimatedOpacity(
        child: child,
        opacity: frame == null ? 0 : 1,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    },
  )
```